# Poor reach with FCM

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase for an Android SDK currently used by another app. We use it to send push to the users of this app, but right now, we reach only about 65% of the user base ( ~6k out of ~9k). Why is this happening, and how we can correct this ? Thanks

Comment: Hi Laetan. Your post is quite broad as to what would be the issue. There are some scenarios as to why a message can't be received by the client device -- some notifications are explicitly blocked by the user, some are implicitly blocked by the device itself -- just to name a few.

Answer (score 0):

One of the common issue is that the notification token of the device is not updated. You need to check if the device token is updated at regular basis.

Comment: I am using the firebase topics to send messages. Can't really send 9k message manually. And individual token are automaticaly updated.